# In PHP, how to convert all methods to "private"?

Tags: php

I'm creating an automatic mechanism to turn all methods of classes to "private". Then I will add a `__call` method, to track down the callings. The only problem is how to do this without spoiling other strings, comments etc.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Google "PHP refactoring".

Comment: I want to track down all method callings, examine their running time, memory etc

Comment: What's wrong with using the xdebug extension for such things?

Comment: it can give give me details about calling methods, its running time, returned values, consumed memory? How?

Comment: @JohnSmith It is an extension that you install and then enable. See the [installation instructions](http://xdebug.org/docs/install).

Comment: I know what xdebug is, and its code coverage feature

Answer (score 1):

> I want to track down all method callings, examine their running time, memory etc

There are already tools for that, search for php profiling, I could recommend [xhprof](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof).

If for some reason you don't want to use these, try [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php)